# Raw printing with Electron app

Tags: javascript, printing, electron, network-printers, epos

I want to create a electron app that support raw printing.

Any suggestion about a library or path that I can take will be appreciated.I did a little bit of research but nothing seems to be up to date. I want to get all the printers availables and get the default printer and print with it.

I you have a small example that you can show me, It will be awesome!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

After trying several methods and packages, I was able to achieve success by:

- sharing the printer
- using node-cmd to send a copy of the file to the shared printer.

Note, I have only used and tested on Windows.

```
yarn add node-cmd
```

Example

```
const fs = window.require('fs')
const path = window.require('path')
const cmd = window.require('node-cmd')

//Save the raw output to the filesystem
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'rawprint.prn') //or wherever you want to save it

//Create a command to copy the file to the shared printer path (e.g. \\localhost\DPD ). Make sure that var is sanitised first! 
const command = `COPY /B "${filePath}" "${pathToSharedPrinter}"`

cmd.get( command, (err, data, stderr) => {

    if ( !err ) {
        console.log('Success!')
    } else {
        console.log( err.message )
    }

})
```